# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' .Ignoring the spaces for strings

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE primary2(boom text,id int,PRIMARY KEY(boom(5)) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO primary2 VALUES('viok',1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO primary2 VALUES('viok',1);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'viok' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql> INSERT INTO primary2 VALUES('viok ',1);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'viok ' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

STRINGs 'viok' and 'viok ' are different .How to add a string with spaces?

Comment: possible duplicate of [make text column as unique key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033378/make-text-column-as-unique-key)

Comment: I know !!!You do not understand the problem

Comment: The problem is you shouldn't be using a `text` as a unique/primary key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18222436/3503205 Here is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q:** How to add a string with spaces?

**A:** It's not possible.

The TEXT values 'viok' and 'viok ' are *not* unique, in terms of how MySQL stores those as index entries. This is [documented behavior](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html):

> If a TEXT column is indexed, index entry comparisons are space-padded at the end. This means that, if the index requires unique values, duplicate-key errors will occur for values that differ only in the number of trailing spaces. For example, if a table contains 'a', an attempt to store 'a ' causes a duplicate-key error. This is not true for BLOB columns.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL ignores trailing spaces in string comparisons. One way is to add a column to store number of trailing spaces the text has.

One way is to store it as varchar, which allows trailing spaces.