# Unique Key involving string fields

Tags: c#, sql, constraints, trim

I am having some issues with the implementation of a constraint for unique key.

It has 3 fields and one of them is a string. The problem is that I get violation of unique key when I send this two rows:

**DB**

```
First: Id-type int
Second: PosId-type uniqueidentifier
Third: Description-type nvarchar(256)
```

**Defined constraint**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.StAPSachverhalte ADD CONSTRAINT
    UQ_myuniqueKey UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        CompanyId,
        PosId,
        Description
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**C# parameters code**

```
new SqlParameter("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256),
new SqlParameter("@PosId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier),
...
MyParameters1[0].Value = _newData.Description;
MyParameters1[1].Value = _newData.PosId;
```

**CommandText**

```
@"INSERT INTO StAPSachverhalte( 
                    [Description], 
                    [PosId] 
                    ) 
                VALUES ( 
                    @Description, 
                    @PosId) 
                SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()",
```

Sent entries

```
'1, random GUID, 001'

'1, random GUID, 001 '
```

If I am not wrong, both should be valid because '001' <> '001 '.

**Error**

`Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.XXX'. The duplicate key value is (76, 9bcba4e1-4d16-487c-977f-cda933bb0955, 0001 ).`

I try to save the data with a normal sqlcommand executenonquery using paramenters and I check the myparameter[index] contains the corresponding value with an empty space at the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: What fields are in your unique constraint?

Comment: the three fields should be unique together. I omitted the rest of them because they are almost 15...

Comment: What's your database, how you declare the columns in database (types, lenghts, etc), the CODE you're using to execute the SQL command, all information needed to help you

Comment: In any case, I would say that the SQL command is being sending without quotes around the strings, so you are sending two identical rows.

Comment: When using SqlParameters, do I need to specify also with quotes? It is not enough the way I assign the values to the parameters array?

Comment: I do think it should be enough...

Comment: Jacuch when You are using parameters You don't need to use quotes

Comment: It was what I tell. But for some reason, the command he is sending, is thinking that ALL the fields on the unique constrain are the same, or one of the fields are invalid.

Comment: @blacai, if you are SURE that you are sending '001' and '001 ', than the problem is not the string, but another problem.

Comment: I am sure. I tried saving the first row alone. And now I try to save the second. You can see in the error from the DB they have a '0001 ' returning.

Comment: I'm assuming if you change any of the other parameters, it accepts the entry... OK, so you have a problem with the strings. The only thing I can think of is that for some reason, this field nvarchar is been filled with spaces. If so, do not matter if you send '001' or '001   ', it will think it's the same. But I think nvarchar shouldn't be like this (nchar yes)

Comment: Actually '001' and '001 ' are equal for SQL :) Try "select case when '001' = '001 ' then 1 else 0 end" in SSMS query window...

Comment: @Arvo, yes. I found this with a little search... On of the options provided was the one I put in the answer, as the field will be stored with the spaces, the length of the field can be part of the key and, in this case, will create in fact a unique identifier. But somehow, I think allowing "trailing spaces" to be part of a relevant string is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I found the answer is that while you are indeed sending two different strings, the trailing spaces are not taken into account when the DB compare strings. Including the unique comparison when inserting.

So, to work as you want, you have to add another field, like the length of the string, as suggested here: [MySQL database with unique fields ignored ending spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714534/mysql-database-with-unique-fields-ignored-ending-spaces)

Comment: Is this solution also for transact sql?

Comment: @blacai, for what I could found, yes.