# MYSQL not accepting whitespaces

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have created a table in mysql as:

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `age` int(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`age`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am inserting 2 rows in this table as:

```
insert into test1 values(1,'user1','m');
insert into test1 values(1,'user1  ','m');
```

In the second row insertion, I want my 'name' filed to have white space.
But when I run the second query it gives error of primary key violation.

Is there a way I can insert white spaces in the table having primary key also?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714534/mysql-database-with-unique-fields-ignored-ending-spaces

Answer (score 3):

Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. You can declare
a VARCHAR column to be any length between 1 and 255, just as for CHAR
columns. However, in contrast to CHAR, VARCHAR values are stored using
only as many characters as are needed, plus one byte to record the
length. Values are not padded; instead, trailing spaces are removed
when values are stored. (This space removal differs from the SQL-99
specification.)

You probably want lpad, rpad, or space

If you are developing for html you can replace the white space with a different character and once you query the you replace the character with the white space, you can even use `"&nbsp;"` that will insert an empty space into your html browser

Comment: That's interesting, I never knew that VARCHAR automatically removed whitespace. All these years I've spent using PHP trim functions. oh lol.

Comment: Awesome! It might still be safer to develop using trim functions, you never know if it might change is some version and makes the code easier to understand

Comment: @Dave: I am not using php or any other tool. I am inserting the data manually in mysql.

Comment: @kawade if I may ask, why do you have to use the space? Cant you replace it with something else?

Comment: @Dave: Dave i am migrating the data from oracle to mysql and we have the data in oracle, and we cannot delete that data from tables. thats why i need to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert the values with white spaces you can use `name nvarchar(20)` instead of `varchar(20)`

**Note :**
The exact problem is that for SQL norm if you compare two string with different lengths the first thing done by SQL is to make them to the same length by adding trailing spaces.

So, if your query compares string1 'a' and string2 'a ', string1 is first converted to 'a ' then compared to string2, and now the two string are the same.

Finally and fortunately, if the field is a UNIQUE INDEX or Primary key it is not possible to have 'a' and 'a ' in two different rows. If it is not a UNIQUE INDEX or primary key field, then you will have to use RTRIM, LTRIM and LEN function with an extra character like LEN('a'+'#')=2 and LEN('a '+'#')=3.

Len('a') and len('a ') give ...1

What you must keep in mind is :
Remove trailing spaces before insertion ! It will be the better option

I have seen character or string primary key systems speeded up radically when converted to Integer.

Comment: @kawade : Did u inserted any values with white spaces  after altering the table ?