# How to get MySQL "unique" constraint on varchar to not ignore trailing spaces?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, unique, varchar

I am using MySQL.  The single VARCHAR column in tbl1 has a UNIQUE constraint on it.

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('X');

INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('X '); -- Produced "Duplicate entry" due to UNIQUE constraint.
```

In the second INSERT statement, a space is the last character of the value 'X '.  It is distinctly different than the value being inserted in the first INSERT statement where the value is 'X' with no space.

Why is MySQL telling me that these two values are duplicates?
How can I get MySQL to acknowledge the trailing space as part of the value?

Comment: What is the point of the trailing space at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714534/mysql-database-with-unique-fields-ignored-ending-spaces

Comment: The reason is to maintain the integrity of the source data.